# change breadcrumb css based upon pageview -- caching issue

Tags: category, cache, breadcrumbs

when accessing a category page and a product page i'd like to change the breadcrumb css background attribute based upon the category that is being accessed.  So I added some logic within breadcrumbs.phtml that will check for the category title and it will reflect these changes.

Although due to the need for caching, this is not continuously changed and persists, for example, when I visit a product page that doesn't have the same category (or any category whatsoever).

the background image persists on the search page, product page, etc.

```
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>
<?php $key = array_keys($crumbs);
$category = $crumbs[$key[1]['label']];
$first = '<div id="grid-breadcrumbs"';
$mid = 'style="background:url(\'http://website.local/skin/frontend/website/web/images/category_header_';
$last = '.jpg\') no-repeat scroll center top #edf0f1">';
if ($category = 'category1') {
    echo $first . $mid . 'cat1' . $last;
} elseif ($category = 'category2') {
    echo $first . $mid . 'cat2' . $last;
} elseif ($category = 'category3') {
    echo $first . $mid . 'cat3' . $last;
} elseif ($category = 'category4') {
    echo $first . $mid . 'cat4' . $last;
} else {
    echo $first . '>';
}?>
```

The above code essentially generated a dynamic background for grid-breadcrumbs based upon the name of the category.

Is it possible to change the css of a breadcrumb from the category page itself?

Comment: Could you add the changes you've made in `breadcrumbs.phtml`?

Comment: @SanderMangel I added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)):
$key = array_keys($crumbs);
$category = $crumbs[$key[1]]['label'];
$first = '<div id="grid-breadcrumbs"';
$mid = 'style="background:url(\'http://spooltuning.local/skin/frontend/cj-pony/spool/images/category_header_';
$last = '.jpg\') no-repeat scroll center top #edf0f1">';
if ($category == 'Focus ST') {
    echo $first . $mid . 'focus' . $last;
} elseif ($category == 'F-150 EcoBoost') {
    echo $first . $mid . 'F150' . $last;
} elseif ($category == 'Mustang EcoBoost') {
    echo $first . $mid . 'mustang' . $last;
} else {
    echo $first . $mid . 'fiesta' . $last;
}
?>
```

It turns out that the caching issue was not the major hurdle that needed a good leaping. my logical booleans were actually assignment, oh what a misfortune! haha! The category assignment itself was misconfigured.  You can imagine the redfacedness, i'm sure of it!

Answer (score 1):

Each element in the breadcrumbs has a certain class based on what it means.
For example the `home` breadcrumb has the class `home`.
For each category you have the class `category{ID_HERE}`.

I think you can solve this with css by setting styles on the corresponding classes.

Comment: So where would I define this in relation to grid-breadcrumbs?

Comment: What do you mean by relation? Can you add an example to the question?

Comment: I was able to achieve a sufficient answer.  I had a terrible misconstruction of the logic in the above code.  ('=') instead of ('==')...

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer adn mark it as accepted.